# Append dymanic data from sessionStorage (JSON) to Listview

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, listview

I have the following bit of data(JSON) stored in a session:

```
Prescription: [{"medID":"id1","medName":"name1","medQty":"qty1","medDirec":"Directions1"}, {"medID":"id2","medName":"name2","medQty":"qty2","medDirec":"Directions2"}]
```

I want to get these information automatically "displayed" inside a `Listview` (jQuery Mobile) on page `load`, for this I have come up with the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        window.addEventListener('load', OnStorage, false);

    });

    function OnStorage(event) {
        if (window.sessionStorage) {

            var retrievedData = sessionStorage.getItem("Prescription");
            var PrescriptionJSON = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
            var prescLength = PrescriptionJSON.Length();

            for (var i = 0; i < PrescriptionJSON.Length(); i++) {

                var text = '<h2>' + PrescriptionJSON[i].medName + '</h2>' +
                           '<p><strong>Quantity: </strong>' + PrescriptionJSON[i].medQty + '</p>' +
                           '<p><strong>Directions: </strong>' + PrescriptionJSON[i].medDirec + '</p>'
                $('<li />', {
                    html: text
                }).appendTo("#summaryList ul");
                //$("#summaryList").append(text);
                //alert(retrievedData);
            }

            $('#summaryList').listview("refresh");
            $('#summaryList').trigger("create");

        }
    }
```

When I uncomment `//alert(retrievedData);` I get the JSON inside an alert popup, but when I call `//alert(PrescriptionJSON);` (the `parsed` variable) I get something like [object, Object]. Nonetheless, I don't know if this is worth mentioning but just in case I am.

Basically I don't know what is wrong in the script above, because I don't get anything from the JSON data appended to the `listview`.
Just for reference I have this on my HTML side.

```
<ul id="summaryList" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li data-role="list-divider" style="text-align:center">Prescription Summary</li>
</ul>
```

Please note that the length of the data (`Prescription`) will be dynamically created so the length may not always be 2 like the example above.

I have gone through a good 2 hrs researching online and have found similar questions but none could help me solve my problem. I've also had a look at http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/json-what-it-is-how-it-works-how-to-use-it/ and learned a few more things but still have not be able to work my way around my problem.

Any suggestions or questions are greatly welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var PrescriptionJSON =  '[{"medID":"id1","medName":"name1","medQty":"qty1","medDirec":"Directions1"}, {"medID":"id2","medName":"name2","medQty":"qty2","medDirec":"Directions2"}]';
     localStorage.setItem("PrescriptionJSON", PrescriptionJSON);

     function OnStorage(event) {
        if (window.localStorage) {
            var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("PrescriptionJSON");
            var obj = $.parseJSON(retrievedData);
            var li = "";
            $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
                li  += '<li><h2>' + value.medName + '</h2><p><strong>Quantity: </strong>' + value.medQty + '</p><p><strong>Directions: </strong>' + value.medDirec + '</p></li>'       
            })

            $('#summaryList').append(li).trigger("create");
            $('#summaryList').listview("refresh");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wow, that worked perfectly. Thank you! Wasn't familiar with `$.each(obj, function(key, value){}` but now I know! :)